# Selecting distinct records not considering one field

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

I have a table with a composite primary key made of seven fields:

```
PK COD_LTN
PK COD_CANA
PK COD_FAM_PRO
PK COD_CTG_PRO
PK COD_PRO
PK COD_CFG_PRM_PRO
PK COD_FAM_PRM_PRO
```

I have for example these two records:

```
COD_LTN  COD_CANA COD_FAM_PRO COD_CTG_PRO COD_PRO COD_CFG_PRM_PRO COD_FAM_PRM_PRO
00011    SPO      NF          C01         53      A               PZTR
00011    SPO      NF          C01         53      B               PZTR
```

I want to select all the distinct records not considering the field COD_CFG_PRM_PRO:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        COD_LTN,
        COD_CANA,
        COD_FAM_PRO,
        COD_CTG_PRO,
        COD_PRO,
        -- COD_CFG_PRM_PRO, don't consider this
        COD_FAM_PRM_PRO
FROM
        PRM_STATICO_PRO  
WHERE
        COD_PRO=53;
```

Of course it works:

```
COD_LTN  COD_CANA COD_FAM_PRO COD_CTG_PRO COD_PRO COD_FAM_PRM_PRO
00011    SPO      NF          C01         53      PZTR
```

But I also want to select the field `COD_CFG_PRM_PRO` that makes the record distinct, that is I want only one record:

```
COD_LTN  COD_CANA COD_FAM_PRO COD_CTG_PRO COD_PRO COD_CFG_PRM_PRO COD_FAM_PRM_PRO
00011    SPO      NF          C01         53      A               PZTR
```

I can't find how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use group by and min functions to solve this -

```
SELECT Cod_Ltn,
       Cod_Cana,
       Cod_Fam_Pro,
       Cod_Ctg_Pro,
       Cod_Pro,
       MIN(Cod_Cfg_Prm_Pro),
       Cod_Fam_Prm_Pro
  FROM Prm_Statico_Pro
 WHERE Cod_Pro = 53
 GROUP BY Cod_Ltn,
          Cod_Cana,
          Cod_Fam_Pro,
          Cod_Ctg_Pro,
          Cod_Pro,
          Cod_Fam_Prm_Pro;
```

This will give result as you are expecting..